# Is it appropriate to CC users not directly involved in a reply?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

This question is a minor concern about comment etiquette. Should one use `@` to ping users who you are talking about but not directly talking to in a thread? Both users are posting in the same thread. For example:

Usera: Some comment.

Userb: Like @usera says, *insert comment here*.

Usera doesn't necessarily need to be pinged, though I think the intent here is either to notify Usera so they can offer their input, or because it's idiomatic to use `@` to refer to usernames. However, I can imagine it would be *slightly* annoying in some cases.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about users that did get involved already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526851/multiple-files-makefile-compilation?noredirect=1#comment45371559_28526851) notified me even though gha.st wasn't talking to me.

Comment: But that's only because you were the last to comment on the post.

Answer (score 1):

There is little point in pinging the other user, no. You can link to the comment to bring in context:

```
like [User A said](http://stackoverflow.com/link/to/comment), ...
```

It is not as if using `@username` creates a link for people reading the conversation to follow.

Comment: Personally I think that if it's a discussion I already engaged in, it's because I have an interest in that discussion and I would prefer a notification if something new is brought to the table. I wont get a notification otherwise unless it's in a comment thread under a post I made. I guess YMMV though, I don't get a lot of notifications and I might feel different if I had to sift through 20+ of them each day.

Comment: @ivarni: Some users are going to want to be pinged as often as possible, like you. Others are going to want to be pinged only when absolutely necessary. It's not even really a matter of how many pings/day, but how they approach questions. Some people like to skim hundreds of questions looking for the really good ones; on a decent question, they'll toss out a comment but they don't want to come back. Those are the ones who will get annoyed. But I honestly don't know how you can guess what kind of users you're dealing with just from the comment thread…

Comment: How you managed to read my reply as "I want to be pinged as often as possible" is something I'll probably never going to be able to work out.